# PHP serializing array as object in JSON

Tags: php, json, rest

I'm trying to call a REST endpoint that is expecting an object with an array 'campaigns' and a boolean 'getChildren'.
The issue is that the array is sometimes serialized as an object instead of an array.

The incorrect request I'm getting :

```
   {
    "campaigns":
      {
        "1":"1006352",
        "2":"1006347",
        "3":"1006350",
        "4":"1006349",
        "5":"1006348",
        "6":"1006345",
        "7":"1006344",
        "8":"1006343"
       },
    "getChildren":false
   }
```

What I want (and that I get sometimes) :

```
 {
  "campaigns":["1006351","1006346"],
  "getChildren":false
 }
```

Here is my code :

```php
            $campaignIds = array_map(function ($item) use ($networkIds) {
            return $item->nid;
        },
            array_filter($items, function ($item) use ($networkIds) {
                return empty((int)$item->nb_shared);
            }));

        $consoWithoutChildren = EndpointClient::getConsumptionByCampaign($networkIds, $campaignIds);
```

I want the 'campaigns' parameter to be always interpreted as an array.

I tried json_encode() but it escapes the array, causing issues in the use cases where I had valid JSON, like that :

```
{"campaigns":"[\"1006351\",\"1006346\"]","getChildren":false}
```

Any idea what is wrong ?

Comment: You need to extract and provide a [mcve]. In particular it's unclear how you come to the conclusion that `json_encode()` escapes an array in any way. Also, nobody here knows what happens in the other parts of your program or what e.g. `$networkIds` is.

Answer (score 0):

`array_filter` keeps the index of the array elements.
So if the first element of your array does not fulfill the condition of your `array_filter`, you have no element at the 0 index.
To be serialized properly, the array must not have null values in it.

The solution is to reassign the array elements to 0 to n index, with `array_values()`.

Like this :

```php
        // array_values is needed to have arrays' indices beginning at 0.
        // If not, the JSON parsing would consider the array an object.
        // Like {"campaigns":{"1":"1006352","2":"1006347"}}
        $campaignIds = array_values(
            array_map(
                function ($item) use ($networkIds) {
                    return $item->nid;
                },
                array_filter(
                    $items,
                    function ($item) use ($networkIds) {
                        return empty((int)$item->nb_shared);
                    }
                )
            )
        );

        $consoWithoutChildren = EndpointClient::getConsumptionByCampaign($networkIds, $campaignIds);
```